# Guava LoadingCache - how to handle keys which don't exist in backing store

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and [LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) to implement an in-memory cache of database data.

Suppose a client queries the cache for an item that does not exist in the backing store. I want the client to know that no data was found for the specified key. What is the best approach for handling this?

- Store special value in cache which signifies "no data".
- Store nothing in cache and raise exception.
- Other ideas?

Comment: Well...does that represent an exceptional condition, or is this a normal occurrence in your program?  If the first, throw an exception, if the second, store a special value.

Comment: I've somewhat reluctantly used an `Optional` in the latter of Louis's cases.

Comment: In my case, "no data" is meaningful. Initially, I tried to store null in the cache, which failed due to `InvalidCacheLoadException`. Thanks for the suggestion, Ray. Also found some good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298285/handle-null-value-using-guava-mapmaker-cachebuilder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've always solved this in the following way.

```
interface KeyValueService<K,V> {
    V get(K key);
}

class CachingKeyValueService<K,V> {
    Cache<K,Optional<V>> cache;
    V get(K key) {
        return cache.get(key).orNull();
    }

}
```

Ideally you would change the interface for KeyValueService to always return Optional, but sometimes thats not possible.

You can use weighting to cause all Optional.ABSENT references to be evicted quickly.

Comment: I don't think you can use weighing to cause Optional.ABSENT to be evicted quickly. From the CacheBuilder docs: "weight is only used to determine whether the cache is over capacity; it has no effect on selecting which entry should be evicted next".

Comment: You are right in that it doesn't aid selection, however once it starts evicting it will keep evicting until it is under the weight, if you make Optional.ABSENT a lower weight than a regular object, they will be preferentially evicted during an eviction cycle. Standard LRU rules still apply of course.