# Object to number to number conversion in Java. Any methods in common libraries?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

Our project use google guava, apache commons and maybe other libraries with common tasks and I was wondering if these libraries contain methods which does null safe conversions (object to number, object to string). As for now I wrote myself some helper methods, e.g :

```
int parseInteger(Object obj) {
        if (obj!= null) {
            if (obj instanceof Integer) return (Integer) obj;
            if (obj instanceof Long) return ((Long) obj).intValue();
            return Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you don't have to care about that `parseInteger(null)` and `parseInteger(0L)` have the same result? Lucky you ;)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can use this `if (obj instanceof Number) return ((Number) obj).intValue();` instead of two separate `Integer`/`Long` checks.

Comment: To Andreas_D's point, see Louis Wasserman's answer to [Handle null value using Guava MapMaker/CacheBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298285/handle-null-value-using-guava-mapmaker-cachebuilder)

Comment: thanks, I was almost sure it's not by far the optimal way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing like this in Guava. As already pointed

> Guava tries to force you to avoid using null wherever possible, because improper or undocumented behavior in the presence of null can cause a huge amount of confusion and bugs. I think it's definitely a good idea to avoid using nulls wherever possible, and if you can modify your code so that it doesn't use null, I strongly recommend that approach instead.

A similar argument applies to `parseEverythingAsInt`. You're looking for a method accepting *anything* and returning an `int`. The very existence of such a method encourages people to write methods returning *anything*. This is surely no good practice, as being strict helps to prevent errors. That's why I'm quite sure there's no such method in Guava.

<sup>Maybe my answer should better be a comment, but it's too long and I don't think there'll be a positive answer, anyway.</sup>